# How to get localStorage before rendering reactjs components in universal app?

Tags: node.js, local-storage, react-router, redux

I am storing "some" user's session data in the client's `localStorage`, I need to get this data after server rendering and before the reactjs app is loaded so I can check if the user session is valid. If the user session is valid, I update the redux store with the user data; otherwise, I leave it as is.

I am using react-router's `onEnter` hook to check if the user's session is valid. The problem is that I am requesting the data saved in the `localStorage` on the server side (which I know is not available).

Therefore, I need a way to check the `localStorage` after the server render and have it ready for the `onEnter` hook.

I would also like to know if there is a way, while on the server side, to request the client's `localStorage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to sort out the logic in between `createStore` and `render()` in your `client.js` file.

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
const store = createStore();

if(localStorage.get('token')) {
    store.dispatch(authenticate(localStorage.get('token')));
}

render(
    <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>,
    document.getElementById('js-react')
);
```

Keep in mind that if there is any asynchronous code in the `authenticate` action creator that you will then need to wait for it to finish before you can render.

Comment: I should also note that there is currently no way to get `localStorage` information on the server.